# How can I print the memory usage in KB by free?

Tags: scripting, memory, free

I need to print the RAM memory used at this time in kilobytes(KB) with command `free`, how can I do that with one line command

input: `free` ...

output: 567595

output should be contain only kilobytes (KB)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to this site. To get to your question, could you [please edit your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/483040/edit) to include what you have tried so far. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please decide do you want output in bytes or kilobytes!

Comment: kilobytes i specify in description

Answer (score 3):

The command you are looking for is:

```
free -k
```

This is easy discoverable in the man page of `free` command

> Options The -b switch displays the amount of memory in bytes; the -k
>   switch (set by default) displays it in kilobytes; the -m switch
>   displays it in megabytes.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, just `free` would output the memory in kilobytes anyway, since it's the default setting.

Comment: @fragamemnon, if you check the 1st revision of the question OP want output in **bytes**

Comment: Noted. I feel that the answer should account for the edited question. You are absolutely correct in your answer to the original question.